# Organizer.displayName is null for some users

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I am using the Google Calendar apps API in Android. For some users in my organization the field `displayName` is always null for an Organizer* instance that represents them. To get the organizer and display name I call `eventInstance.getOrganizer().getDisplayName()`.

It's not for all accounts, though. I can't figure out the pattern here. Does something need to be set in their Google account? Why would the display name not be available, anyway?

P.S. - I haven't gotten to parsing attendees yet but I assume the same issue will exist there.

References:

* com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event.Organizer

Answer (score 1):

It usually happens to users who have not enabled Google+ on their accounts. You can refer [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/19). For now, make sure that you enable Google+ on your domain and then on your account. If still persists, try deleting the account from your app's accounts list for your account to be updated properly.

Comment: This does seem to line up with what I've seen: users with Google+ have a display name, and those that don't do not have a display name. 

The question is, how am I supposed to get the user's name? Having everyone create a Google+ account is not an option. Is there a different API I should be using?

Comment: For those looking still looking for a solution in the days since Google+ was shut down, the answer lies in its replacement, "Currents".  If you have Google Apps for Business, make sure Currents is available for your users, and then from within Currents, make sure the users you want to have displayName work for have an "active profile". As an admin for the organization, you can make them active on users' behalf.